# Unable to resolve module 'react-devtools-core' from 'node-modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js'

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Trying to debug react native iOS application but when I am running the app from xcode, getting this error.

['react-devtools-core' from 'node-modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI5Jz.jpg)

Comment: Have you try run app after kill all node process?

Comment: Yeah and I have also tried to remove node_modules and again run npm install but then I got version mismatch error once and after it again I am getting the same error mentioned above.